# how to unwrap the multiple parents elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am getting the `html` decoded from server. once i receive that's look like this:

it has spans simply nested inside of no.of span's

```
<p><span><span><span><span>The portacabin consist of toilets, <strong></strong> <strong>\u003e\u0026#160;</strong> showers and changing cubicles, a classroom, an office and a store room.&nbsp;<br>The
 upgrade shall include development of foot paths and installation of new
 up-lights around the area complete with all the required &amp; 
necessary directional signages, as per the Standards Engineering 
Specification &amp; approval by client.</span></span></span></span></p>
```

I would like to remove the `span` whichever not required, even if it has only `space`. how to do this?

i tried this:

```
var p = $('p').contents().unwrap();

console.log(p);
```

there is a empty strong element and with only `space` with strong elment - how to clear it?

It unwraps  step, that's it.
Any one help me please?

[Live](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbyb1exm/)

Comment: I don't see any "empty" `span`s in that block of text, just four nested ones. Could you clarify?

Comment: yes, i would like to remove the nested ones.. (unnecessarily nested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.nodeType` property to test for text-level nodes, then match them against the whitespace regex `/\s*/`:

```
if (this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    this.innerText.match(/\s*/) && $(this).unwrap();
}
```

You can place that in a loop with the `.each()` function to flatten each level of `span`-s, and iterate that over all `span`s. Here's a fiddle showing a basic version of this: http://jsfiddle.net/LwmoLp3o/2/

Comment: Yes works. can you add a facility to remove the empty elements? even which has just `spaces` or `multiple spaces`..?

Comment: @3gwebtrain Yes, just add a `$(this).text().match()` condition to it, and iterate over `strong`. Looking back I made several obvious errors in that fiddle... Updated now